# Numpy indexing in 3 dimensions

Tags: numpy

```
In [93]: a = np.arange(24).reshape(2, 3, 4)
In [94]: a[0, 1, ::2]
Out[94]: array([4, 6])
```

Can someone explain what '::2' means here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

::2 means : in this dimension, get all the "layers" having a pair index (starting from 0, counting by 2).

it means: get the element at a[0, 1, 0] and a[0, 1, 2] and put it into the same array.

each index position (you have 3 in this sample) is indexable and "sliceable". perhaps you saw slices like [this:slice] before in normal arrays. well... slices can also have a third value which is the "step" value.

so: [a:b:c] means [startPosition:endPosition:step] where endPosition is not included.
so having ::2 means start=0, end=the end of the ... dimension, step=2.

you have at most 4 in that dimension (see your reshape line), so the index it will count are 0 and 2 (1 and 3 are skipped, and 3 is the last element).

0 0 0 => 0
0 0 1 => 1
0 0 2 => 2
0 0 3 => 3
0 1 0 => 4 -> (0, 1, 0) is rescued via the slice
0 1 1 => 5
0 1 2 => 6 -> (0, 1, 2) is rescued via the slice

Comment: yes, it's the same. consider that you can use slices in any dimension. you could have done [::2, ::2, ::2] if you wanted, obtaining a different result.